# Take the value of designation table and make the field for menu table

Tags: django, database, django-models

Models.py

```
class Designation(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def __str__(self):
       return self.Name
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'desingnation'
```

all the data should create as field to another table

Comment: You need to be more specific. What other table? What data? What field? Why doesn't `ForeignKey` do the trick? Your question is unclear.

Comment: i updated my question please refer above

Comment: That's not clarifying anything. What value of designation table are you talking about? And what's the menu table? And you're not explaining why you can't use a ForeignKey to link the two tables. Learn how to [ask] a good question, so we can understand the problem you're facing.

Comment: @dirkgroten Did you got our point